# Updating a software using .exe is not copying latest dlls in C: drive but updating version in control Panel

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installshield

Steps to reproduce:

1. Version of the my application already installed on my windows machine is 10.11.0.3, same version is present in control panel and registry.
2. Have made few changes and updated the .ism file (newer version: 10.11.0.4) Run the jenkins jobs.
3. New .exe is created.
4. After running .exe and it detects that the software is already installed on my machine and asks whether you want to upgrade to newer version.
5. After installation, it updates the version of the software in control panel to be 10.11.0.4.
   Registry too gets updated.
6. But the dlls present in C:/ are still to be of older version.
   The new dlls are not getting copied.

Please Suggest how the version is getting updating in control panel but not in the C: drive, user is admin user, not an issue of permissions.

Comment: I don't know what installer you are using, but MSI only uses 3 points not 4. Specifically, the MSI is ignoring the .3 and the .4, so the version it is seeing is 10.11.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productversion?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Also, when building a new installer, if I'm not making a 'patch', I randomize the GUID to a new one for the Product Code GUID (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productcode)

Comment: I tried as suggested. 1. Updated the ProductCode and tried to update, Result: Installer did not recognize an older version but installed application as fresh application, not as per expected it should recognize that there is an older version and should update it. 2. Used 10.11.1 as the upgrade version but same behaviour, not updating the dll but the version in control panel.

Comment: The product code needs to change each installer, but the Upgrade Code (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgradecode) needs to stay the same from installer to installer. Also it should default to overwrite, but there is an MSI setting for each component to tell it to 'Never Overwrite'. I guess maybe check for that? Last are you sure it's even installing the correct version? Have you tried to do a clean install or install to a different folder to make sure the newer DLL is being included?

Comment: so i checked the GAC, after installing latest version 10.11.0.4 the gac has older version only which is 10.11.0.3. Ok let me check these things